# Fastest way to remove duplicate points on the edges of polygon?

Tags: algorithm

As shown following, I have a polygon that contains the integer points:

```
type
  TPoint = array [1 .. 2] of Integer;
  TPointArray = array of TPoint;
```

The points on edges are given in clock-wise order, and I want to remove the intermediate points (marked as red).

For example, given any continuous 3 points A, B, C if  B is exactly on the line between A and C, then B can be safely removed.

How can I do this in fast and efficient manner?

My Psedu-code is:

```
procedure RemovePoints(var pt: TPointArray);
var
  i, j, sz, k, u: integer;
  xoffset, yoffset: integer;
begin
  sz := High(pt);
  i := 0;
  while (True) do
  begin
    Inc(i);
    // points represent array index, so can't be negative,
    // we use -1 to mark deletion
    if (pt[i][1] = -1) then continue;
    if (i = 0) then
    begin
      break; // finish a loop
    end;
    j := i + 1;
    if (j > sz) then
    begin
      j := 0;
    end;
    k := j + 1;
    if (k > sz) then
    begin
      k := 0;
    end;
    if ((pt[i][1] - pt[j][1] = pt[j][1] - pt[k][1]) and ((pt[i][2] - pt[j][2] = pt[j][2] - pt[k][2]))) then
    begin
      // remove pt[j];
      pt[j][1] := -1;
    end;
  end;
  // TODO: shrink the array to remove deleted points
end;
```

[image: Polygon Points on edges]

Comment: Have you done any coding efforts so far?

Comment: my code is quite messy and to be honest. My idea is to loop for all the points (if not marked duplicate) as the starting point and check the next two points for duplication...but I feel the code is disgusting.

Comment: I'd advise you to post at least part of it anyway so people looking at your question can suggest how you could make it better/more performatic.

Comment: I'd start with 2 neighbouring points and check if the next one is on the same line. If yes, drop the second point; if no advance by one point.

Comment: re-edited the question and my code pasted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Walk through the list and consider triplets of adjacent points **p**, **q** and **r**. determine the forward-facing vectors **pq** and **qr** and check whether they are collinear. If so and if they are facing in the same direction, mark the point for deletion.

In a second pass, filter out the marked points.

Two vectors are collinear if their cross product is the null vector. The cross product of vectors in a plane has only one component perpendicular to that plane. So check:

```
pq.x * qr.y - pq.y * qr.x == 0
```

If you want to make sure you don't remove the sharp points of a panhandle, check whether the dot product of the vector is positive:

```
pq.x * qr.x + pq.y * qr.y > 0
```

Because you have integer coordinates, these checks should be straightforward.

Here's a solution that uses your nomenclature and types. It keeps track of which nodes to delete in a separate array. (You can't mark the coordinates with dummy values, because you still need the coordinates intact when you determine whether to delete the next node.)

```
procedure RemovePoints(var pt: TPointArray);
Var i, j: Integer;
    p, q, r: TPoint;
    ax, ay: Integer;
    bx, by: Integer;
    del: Array of Boolean;

begin
  if Length(pt) > 2 then begin
    SetLength(del, Length(pt));
    for i := 0 to Length(pt) - 1 do del[i] := False;

    j := Length(pt) - 1;
    p := pt[j - 1];
    q := pt[j];

    for i := 0 to Length(pt) - 1 do begin
      r := pt[i];

      ax := q[1] - p[1];
      ay := q[2] - p[2];
      bx := r[1] - q[1];
      by := r[2] - q[2];

      if (ax*by - ay*bx = 0) and (ax*bx + ay*by > 0) then del[j] := True;

      p := q;
      q := r;
      j := i;
    end;

    j := 0;
    for i := 0 to Length(pt) - 1 do begin
      if not del[i] then begin
        pt[j] := pt[i];
        inc(j);
      end;
    end;

    SetLength(pt, j);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesn't work for all cases. Consider a polygon with 4 vertices (100,0) (0,0) (100,100) (100,0). The cross product measure alone will delete vertices 0 and 3. Adding the dot product test won't delete any. What you really want is to delete either vertex 0 or 3 but not both.

Comment: @keith969: Hm, this is a degenerate case where two adjacent points are identical, so that the difference vector is the null vector. This answer deals only with deleting the intermediary points. If you want to detect duplicate nodes, you must add another check.

Comment: Yes the trick seems to be to delete points one at a time. Use a loop to keep trying to delete a point, and break if none were deleted.

Answer (score 0):

We already know that we can perfectly define a line using the slope-intercept equation. This means that we can also uniquely define a line using slope and one point through which that line passes.

Starting from the first point in your list of points of polygon, calculate the slope of line passing through the first point and the next one. This is the first slope value for you. Store this value as `currentSlope`. Create a `newPointList` for storing the new edge points. Next:

1. Iterate through all the points starting from third point;
2. If the slope of second and third point is the same as `currentSlope`

   1. This implies second point is on the same line as first and third, so skip this point
   2. `continue` the loop reaching back to step 1.
3. If the slope of second and third point is different from `currentSlope`

   1. It implies that edge defined by first and second point is different from edge defined by second and third point.
   2. Store first and second point in a `newPointList` and update the value of `currentSlope` to the slope between second and third point.

When the iteration will end, `newPointList` will contain only vertices of your polygon.

Answer (score 0):

been fighting with this problem for few hours and looks like DouglasPeucker with 0 sqTolerance works ok.

```
function getSqSegDist(p, p1, p2) {

var x = p1.x,
    y = p1.y,
    dx = p2.x - x,
    dy = p2.y - y;

if (dx !== 0 || dy !== 0) {

    var t = ((p.x - x) * dx + (p.y - y) * dy) / (dx * dx + dy * dy);

    if (t > 1) {
        x = p2.x;
        y = p2.y;

    } else if (t > 0) {
        x += dx * t;
        y += dy * t;
    }
}

dx = p.x - x;
dy = p.y - y;

return dx * dx + dy * dy;
}

function simplifyDPStep(points, first, last, sqTolerance, simplified) {
var maxSqDist = sqTolerance,
    index;

for (var i = first + 1; i < last; i++) {
    var sqDist = getSqSegDist(points[i], points[first], points[last]);

    if (sqDist > maxSqDist) {
        index = i;
        maxSqDist = sqDist;
    }
}

if (maxSqDist > sqTolerance) {
    if (index - first > 1) simplifyDPStep(points, first, index, sqTolerance, simplified);
    simplified.push(points[index]);
    if (last - index > 1) simplifyDPStep(points, index, last, sqTolerance, simplified);
}
}

function simplifyDouglasPeucker(points, sqTolerance) {
var last = points.length - 1;

var simplified = [points[0]];
simplifyDPStep(points, 0, last, sqTolerance, simplified);
simplified.push(points[last]);

return simplified;
}
```

see [simplifyDouglasPeucker](https://jsfiddle.net/nsenkevich/dbksrj4w/2/)